# No 'Move to Trash' in Files for symlinked directory

Tags: directory, symbolic-link

I have a symbolic link to a directory of another user.  The directory has group write permission and I have done 'newgrp' to that group. On the command line I can 'touch', 'rm', 'mv' to that directory.  However, Thunderbird does not put a file there with "Print to File" (even though it acts like it is printing with a progress bar) and Files does not show a "Move to Trash" option for files that are there.  How are programs like Files and Thunderbird different from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

When I start a console session I have not yet done a 'newgrp' for the symlinked directory.  Thunderbird started from the command line after 'newgrp' does write to the directory.

Explanation: When you log in with a graphical console, the start-up scripts such as 'bashrc' are run.  Presumably you do not have a 'newgrp' command in them.  So then any graphical app you start from the menu bar inherits that environment.  When you open a terminal app, it starts a new shell that inherits that environment also.  After you do 'newgrp' in that terminal, any app started from that terminal will inherit that group, but the original environment is not changed.

Solution: If you set the 's' permission bit for the group (chmod g+s ) and if your 'groups' response includes the group which owns that directory, then when you write to the directory it keeps its original group and does not try to change it to your primary group (first group listed by 'groups'). You cannot change the group of a directory you do not own.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? Please develop a bit more so others can understand.